# Output html file from database - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Let's say I have a db table called `example` and inside I have a file location `example.html`. Is there a way using laravel to get that file location from the database and display it in a div? File is stored locally and so my webserver runs locally at the moment.

Any guidance or help will be appreciated.

Comment: you want to show source code from the example.html ?

Comment: @Edgard Leal Well yes, so basically I have a set of templates on the website and what I want to do is to add an option so once a template is clicked it gets a html file location from the database, send it back to the page and display that page on my website so people can see it and then also display source code below it

Answer (score 0):

You can get file's path and name from database, then you just need to include that file. If its path is `/pages` and the its name is `example.html` you can do this:

```
$path = '/pages';
$filename = 'example.php';
include($path."/".$filename);
```

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
>   mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
>   end.

From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

Answer (score 0):

To include html content,  you can use:

```
$html = file_get_contents("file.html");
echo $html; // this works like incluide html inside you PHP file
```

To show html scaped inside you Laravel template you should use double curly brace syntax

```
{!! $html !!}
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)